# dojo how to calculate bubble chart size?

Tags: dojo

I am programming using dojo chart. We are currently implementing a Bubble chart. But I do not know where I'm having difficulties how to calculate the size of Bubble chart. for example, x:340000, y:500000, size: 400000 the data I give you this error occurs on 400000. How do you calculate the size? Please help by all means. Because of this, we spend a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a couple of extra steps that Dojo does not implement for you (whereas richer tools like Excel do).

First, you need to size the bubbles relative to the units of your axes (I always use the Y-axis which in my case is the shortest).  If the Y-axis has a range of 0 through 12 and the X-axis has 2000-2014 then your bubbles should be no larger than 12, though obviously if any was that big it would crowd out and hide other bubbles.

Second, it helps to have a maximum bubble size e.g. 2 units (per the example above).  This could be implemented as a ratio of, say, 1/5th the range of the Y-axis.

Third, if you compare the output of your bubble chart with a bubble chart in Excel you will see that there they resize the bubbles around an average value.  For example if the average of your sizes is 5, you can increase the size of bubbles less than 5 by a factor and decrease the size of those over 5 by the same factor (I use 15%).

Off-topic tip: the order in which the series points are added affects the z-order of the bubbles that are plotted.  You may wish to experiment with the order.